# validate dynamic row text field

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

My  script for dynamic row:

```
 function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");

        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name="chkbox[]";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        element2.name ="terms_desc"; 
        element2.setAttribute('size', '80');
        cell2.appendChild(element2);
     }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
      try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }
      }catch(e) {
          alert(e);
      }
    }
```

my jsp  coding i want to validate each and every new row text field.

```
<table  id="regforms">

<tr><td>
            <table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>

        <td> <input type="text" name="terms_desc" size="80" /> </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
```

please any one help for this to validate each and every row created by using this.
addRow and deleteRow use to add and delete dynamic row

my validation code

```
function val()
{
if (document.forms[0]['terms_desc'].value == 0)
{
alert("Please Enter Terms");
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: What in the new row do you want to validate and how do you intend to do that? Where is the call to addRow()?

Comment: Do you want to validate but you didn't do any validation. Where the code that validates?